# Sqoop compression codec: snappy vs org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

Tags: sqoop, codec, snappy

When using `--compression-codec` with Sqoop, some examples use `--compression-codec snappy` while some use `--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec`.

Are they both refer to the same thing?  If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

snappy and  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec both are same. you can use either one.